# How can I sort and delete lines based on only the 3rd column in CSV file?

Tags: linux, csv, sorting, line

I have a CSV file that has 6 columns separated with `;` on each line (so, technically, "SSV" - semicolon-separated values).

Based on the third value, I would like to delete lines in order to have a smaller file.

If the third value is unique, repeated twice or three times in the file I want to delete all those lines. Only if the third value can be found in other lines' third column *four times or more* I do not want to touch it.

```
sort -t ';' -k3,3 input.txt
```

I can sort the file based on the third column; however, I just couldn't figure it out how I should proceed to scan and delete based on my conditions.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple two-pass Awk solution. On the first iteration, just collect statistics for each value. In the second iteration, print or don't based on the frequency of the current value.

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS=";"} 
  NR==FNR { ++a[$3]; next }
  a[$3]>3' input.txt input.txt
```

`input.txt` is repeated twice to make Awk read the file twice. `FS=OFS=";"` sets the input and output field separator to semicolon before starting the main script. The condition `NR==FNR` is true on the first round through; here, we simply collect the frequency of each value in the array `a` and skip the rest of the script. The condition `a[3]>3` is thus then used in the second iteration through the file to decide which lines to print.

Awk is easy to learn and understand; you should be able to compose something like this yourself after briefly familiarizing yourself with the tool.

Reading the file twice is going to make the processing potentially slower than a one-pass solution, but will be reasonably robust even with large input files, and simplifies the overall processing tremendously.